# Fibonacci sequence. Time Complexity

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, fibonacci

First of all - yes, I know that there are a ton kind of similar questions about this but I still don't get it.

So the Big-O Notation of this code is O(2^n)

```
 public static int Fibonacci(int n)
    {
        if (n <= 1)
            return n;
        else
            return Fibonacci(n - 1) + Fibonacci(n - 2);
    }
```

And even though if I run it using let's say **6** , function is getting called **25** times as you can see in this picture:

[Fibonacci](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XymO.png)
Shouldn't it be **64** because of O(2^6) = 64 ?

Comment: That code is wrong, it gives `Fib(0)` to be `0`, when it should be `1`

Comment: @Alexander That depends if you refer to `fib(0) = fib(1) = 1` or `fib(1) = fib(2) = 1`, both are fine - only depends where you start indexing from.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Also: `O(2^(n - 1))` is still `O(2^(n))`. An offset by a constant is trumped by `n` as `n` approaches infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues with the logic here:

1. Big O notation is only giving upper asymptotic bound, not a tight bound, that's what [big Theta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10376740/572670) is for.
2. Fibonacci is actually `Theta(phi^n)`, if you are looking for tighter bound (where `phi` is the "golden ration", `phi ~= 1.618`.
3. When talking about asymptotic notation, there isn't much point in talking about low numbers, and neglecting the constants - since they are omitted for the asymptotic complexity (This is not the case here though).

In here, the issue is fibonacci is indeed `O(2^n)`, but that bound is not tight, so the actual number of calls is going to be lower than the estimated one (for sufficiently large `n`, onwards).

Comment: Thanks, I have a better understanding now. Could you please take a look at this -  [Fibonacci](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence) There is an answer on this thread by one person who "draws" pyramids to visually show how to get O(2^n). He uses the same algorithm and starts on `Fib(6)` and somehow manages to get 64. That's a part I don't understand. Could you please comment on that?

Comment: @Daniel There is already a comment by Avik there, saying the pyramid is wrong, for `F(3)` is being called 3 times, not 4: F(6) = F(5) + F(4) = F(4) + `F(3) + F(3) + F(2) = F(3) + F(2) + F(3) + F(3) + F(2)`. (The same mistake then follows in the next rows as well).