# If O(n) and Big omega(1) then we can also say that is theata(log n)?

Tags: time-complexity

Please excuse me if this is a stupid question, but I want to make sure. I was thinking log n is in between of the n and 1 so maybe it could work too. or we can call it theta (log n) only when the function is O(log n ) and big omega(log n ) ?

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376740/what-exactly-does-big-%D3%A8-notation-represent

Answer (score 1):

No, O means "faster than or equal to" and Ω means "slower than or equal to". So f could still be Ɵ(1) or Ɵ(n). Also, there are an infinite number of complexity classes between the bounds, such as Ɵ(log log n).