# complexity class of functions

Tags: function, math, complexity-theory, notation

What would these statements mean if `f(n)` and `g(n)` are functions over natural numbers?

1. `g(n)` is in `Θ(f(n))`.

and

2. An algorithm is in the complexity class `Θ(f(n))`.

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471199/what-is-the-difference-between-%CE%98n-and-on

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about practical programming but rather belongs on [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) once the questioner has added more of his own work and explained just where he is stuck.

Answer (score 0):

1. `g(n)` is bracketed by `a.f(n)` and `b.f(n)` (where `a<b` are two constants) for sufficiently large `n`.
2. The running time of the algorithm is of order `Θ(f(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

If `g(n)` is in `Θ(f(n)))` then there exist real constants `a` and `b` greater than zero and an integer constant `n0` greater than zero such that for all `n > n0`, `a * f(n) <= g(n) <= b * f(n)`. For instance, the function `g(n) = (1 + sin(n)) * n^2` is `O(n^2)` because we can choose `a = 1`, `b = 2` and `n0 = 1` and verify the inequalities hold.

If an algorithm is in the complexity class `Θ(f(n))`, then the relation `G` which maps inputs of size `n` to numbers of operations `m` taken to process that input on some implied computer has the following properties:

1. Both `min({m | G(n, m)})` and `max({m | G(n, m)})` are defined.
2. The function `g(n) = min({m | G(n, m)})` is in `Θ(f(n))`.
3. The function `h(n) = max({m | G(n, m)})` is in `Θ(f(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

For a formal definition of Big Θ notation have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations).
A more descriptive explanation you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10376776/7655409).

For an algorithm `n` is the size of the input data (for example the number of elements in a list/array/…) and you will get an estimate of the „cost“ of your algorithm for increasing `n`.
Cost typically means number of elementary operations (arithmetic operations, comparisons, conditions).

Simple example for an „algorithm“: accessing an arbitrary element in a container of size `n`:

- for an array you can access each element directly. So cost is constant, meaning `f(n) = 1` in your notation
- for a linked list you have iterate through the list from begin. So on average you have to pass half of the list: `f(n) = n/2` (or equivalently `f(n) = n`).