# Need help figuring out whether this statement is correct

Tags: big-o

I have been tasked with figuring out whether this statement is correct or not

[image]

Is the expression on the left equal to big theta of *n^3*?

From my understanding it would be true if we were talking big O, since *n^3* is the fastest growing term, but I am not sure with big theta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let

```
f(n) = 1/4 n^3 + n^2 log(n) + 17 n^2
```

then

```
f(n)/n^3 = 1/4 + log(n)/n + 17/n
```

so

```
lim f(n)/n^3 = 1/4 + 0 + 0 = 1/4
```

meaning that `-ε < f(n)/n^3 - 1/4 < ε` for `n > n0`. Take `ε = 1/8`. Then

```
1/4 - 1/8 < f(n)/n^3 < 1/8 + 1/4
1/8 < f(n)/n^3 < 3/8
n^3 < 8f(n) < 3n^3
```

Taking `ϴ()`

```
ϴ(n^3) <= ϴ(f(n)) <= ϴ(n^3)
```

because `ϴ` sees all multiplicative factors as `1`.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer towards the solution.

As explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376740/what-exactly-does-big-%D3%A8-notation-represent) big-theta means your function gets "squeezed" between big-O and big-Omega as n grows.

To prove that statement is correct you need to prove that the expression is equivalent to O(n^3) and Omega(n^3).