# Big theta, Big O, Omega running times of functions

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I'm currently reading up on running times for algorithms. 
I understand the different terms of Big O, Theta and Omega... Lower, upper etc bounding...

However I have some assignments which requires me to list the Theta times. 
An example could be `log(n)+n*sqrt(n)`

In general one could just set the upper bound, but that's not the Theta bounding. 
How on earth do you find the theta bounding of a function?

Until now I've just basically applied the big O bounding as the theta bound. However I'm concerned that this isn't correct at all.

Comment: Just calculate upper and lower bounds separately.  Sandwich them closely enough.  For example `n * sqrt(n) < log(n) + n * sqrt(n) < 2n * sqrt(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, this is `Theta(n*sqrt(n))`.

Why?

1. This is `O(n*sqrt(n))` because `lim [n->inf] n*sqrt(n)+logn]/n*sqrt(n) < infinity`
2. This is `Omega(n*sqrt(n))` because `lim [n->inf] n*sqrt(n) + logn / n*sqrt(n) > 0`.

This means, `n*sqrt(n)` gives us both asymptotic lower bound (Omega) and asymptotic upper bound (O) - and thus is also Theta.

More info in: [What exactly does big Ө notation represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10376740/572670)