# Is it possible for an algorithm's runtime to be defined by two different Big thetha notations?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

For an algorithm with a run time of say, the form `T(n) = 3n^2+ 2n + 5`
I get that there can be multiple Big-O and Omega notations (like O(n^2) and O(n^3) in the given case).

But is it possible for a algorithm to have two Big-Thetha notations describing it?
If yes, can you please give an explanation and if not, why not?

In other terms - Is it possible for two different functions to tightly bind the asymptotic running time of an algorithm?

Comment: please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12338937/6129793

Comment: Constant factors don't matter, so Theta(f(n)) and Theta(5*f(n)) would be two different expressions (but they mean basically the same).

Comment: Hi, Ik what the different notations represent, probably my question is more mathematical, I wanna know if its possible for a function to have two different functions that tightly bind its running time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, provided the two "Big-Theta" functions are Big-Theta to each other.

For example, the running time of Heapsort is both Θ(log n!) and Θ(n log n).

Comment: Ah that seems to make some sense but how does that wrap out, I mean how are "log n" and "n log n" Big-theta to each other?

Comment: @Ayush: log n! .

Comment: Ah right, my bad, but still I dont get how they both are big-theta to each other :(

Comment: @Ayush: any idea of the asymptotic behavior of log n! ?

Comment: Sorry, no! Is there a simpler example?

Comment: Another example would be two different polynomials with the same high order term. In fact Theta(f(n)) is a set of functions. You can use any member as representative.

Comment: @Ayush: `Tn` (n-th triangular number) and `n²`.

Comment: @Ayush See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation for the behavior of `log(n!)`.  Basically `log(n!) = n log(n) - n + O(log(n))`.  From a Big-theta perspective, all that matters is the leading `n log(n)`.