# Why O(n log n) is greater than O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, space-complexity

I read that `O(n log n)` is greater than `O(n)`, I need to know why is it so?

For instance taking `n` as 1, and solving `O(n log n)` will be `O(1 log 1)` = O(0). On the same hand `O(n)` will be `O(1)`?

Which actually contradicts `O(n log n) > O(n)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let us start by clarifying what is `Big O` notation in the current context. From ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)) one can read:

> **Big O notation is a mathematical notation** that describes the limiting
> behavior of a function when the argument tends **towards a particular
> value or infinity**. (..) **In computer science,** big O notation is used to classify algorithms
> according to how their run time or space requirements grow **as the
> input size grows**.

The following statement is not accurate:

> For instance taking n as 1, solving O(n log n) will be O(1 log 1) =
> O(0). On the same hand O(n) will be O(1)?

One cannot simply perform "O(1 log 1)" since the `Big O` notation does not represent a function but rather a [set of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376740/what-exactly-does-big-%D3%A8-notation-represent) with a certain asymptotic upper-bound; as one can read from [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation):

> Big O notation characterizes functions according to their growth
> rates: different functions with the same growth rate may be
> represented using the same `O` notation.

Informally, in computer-science [time-complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) and [space-complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) theories, one can think of the `Big O` notation as a categorization of algorithms with a certain worst-case scenario concerning time and space, respectively. For instance, `O(n)`:

> An algorithm is said to take linear time/space, or O(n) time/space, if its time/space complexity is O(n). Informally, this means that the running time/space increases at most linearly with the size of the input ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Linear_time)).

and `O(n log n)` as:

> An algorithm is said to run in quasilinear time/space if T(n) = O(n log^k n) for some positive constant k; linearithmic time/space is the case k = 1 ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Linearithmic_time)).

Mathematically speaking the statement

> I read that O(n log n) is greater than O(n) (..)

is not accurate, since as mentioned before `Big O` notation represents a [set of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376740/what-exactly-does-big-%D3%A8-notation-represent). Hence, more accurate will be `O(n log n)` contains `O(n)`. Nonetheless, typically such relaxed phrasing is normally used to quantify (for the worst-case scenario) how a set of algorithms behaves compared with another set of algorithms regarding the increase of their input sizes. To compare two classes of algorithms (*e.g.*, `O(n log n)` and  `O(n)`) instead of

> For instance taking n as 1, solving O(n log n) will be O(1 log 1) =
> O(0). On the same hand O(n) will be O(1)?
>
> Which actually contradicts O(n log n) > O(n)

you should analyze how both classes of algorithms behaves with the increase of their input size (*i.e.,* n) for the worse-case scenario; analyzing `n` when it tends to the infinity

[image]

As @[cem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14773728/cem) rightly point it out, in the image "`big-O` denote one of the asymptotically least upper-bounds of the plotted functions, and does not refer to the sets `O(f(n))`"

As you can see in the image after a certain input, `O(n log n)` (green line) grows faster than `O(n)` (yellow line). That is why (for the worst-case) `O(n)` is more desirable than `O(n log n)` because one can increase the input size, and the growth rate will increase slower with the former than with the latter.

Answer (score 11):

I'm going to give the you the *real* answer, even though it seems to be more than one step away from the way you're currently thinking about it...

O(n) and O(n log n) are not *numbers*, or even functions, and it doesn't *quite* make sense to say that one is greater than the other.  It's sloppy language, but there are actually *two* accurate statements that might be meant by saying that "O(n log n) is greater than O(n)".

Firstly, O(f(n)), for any function f(n) of n, is the infinite *set* of all functions that asymptotically grow no faster than f(n).  A formal definition would be:

> A function g(n) is in O(f(n)) if and only if there are constants n0 and C such that g(n) <= Cf(n) for all n > n0.

So O(n) is a set of functions and O(n log n) is a set of functions, and O(n log n) is a *superset* of O(n).  Being a superset is kind of like being "greater", so if one were to say that "O(n log n) is greater than O(n)", they might be referring to the superset relationship between them.

Secondly, the definition of O(f(n)) makes f(n) an *upper bound* on the asymptotic growth of functions in the set.  And the upper bound is greater for O(n log n) than it is for O(n).  In more concrete terms, there a constant n0 such that n log n > n, for all n > n0.  The bounding function itself is asymptotically greater, and this is another thing that one might mean when saying "O(n log n) is greater than O(n)".

Finally, both of these things are mathematically equivalent.  If g(n) is asymptotically greater than f(n), it follows mathematically that O(g(n)) is a superset of O(f(n)), and if O(g(n)) is a proper superset of O(f(n)), it follows mathematically that g(n) is asymptotically greater than f(n).

Therefore, even though the statement "O(n log n) is greater than O(n)" does not strictly make any sense, it has a clear and unambiguous meaning if you're willing to read it charitably.

Answer (score 5):

The [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) only has an *asymptotic* meaning, that is it makes sense only when `n` goes to infinity.

For example, a time complexity of `O(100000)` just means your code runs in constant time, which is asymptotically faster (smaller) than `O(log n)`.