# What is the time-complexity of a program that finds the length of the longest consecutive sequence in an array of integers?

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

Can somebody explain to me what the time-complexity of this program is?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] = { 1, 9, 3, 10, 4, 20, 2};
    ConsecutiveSequence(arr);
}

public static void ConsecutiveSequence(int []a){
    Arrays.sort(a);

    int k =1;
    int n = a.length;
    int max_length=0;
    
    for(int i =0;i<n-1;i++){
        if(a[i]+1==a[i+1]){
            k++;
            if(i==n-2){
                max_length=Math.max(max_length,k);
            }
        }else{
            max_length=Math.max(max_length,k);
            k=1;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(max_length);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity is `N log (N)`. Why?

```
Arrays.sort(a);

for(int i =0;i<n-1;i++){
    if(a[i]+1==a[i+1]){
        k++;
        if(i==n-2){
            max_length=Math.max(max_length,k);
        }
    }else{
        max_length=Math.max(max_length,k);
        k=1;
    }
}
```

The operation:

```
Arrays.sort(a);
```

has a well-know complexity of `N log (N)`. As one [confirm here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int%5B%5D)):

> This algorithm offers O(n log(n)) performance on many data sets that
> cause other quicksorts to degrade to quadratic performance, and is
> typically faster than traditional (one-pivot) Quicksort
> implementations.

For the loop you iterative `n-1` times and for each iteration you performance constant operations. So (N-1) * C.

So the overall complexity is `N log (N) + (N - 1) * c`. Since with increment of the input `N log (N)` grows much faster than (N - 1), the complexity can be represented `by O(N log (N)`). For more information on why  it can be represented by `O(N log (N))` have a look at [this SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65645832/why-on-log-n-is-greater-than-on/65645889#65645889).